# Form elements alignment through generic css

Tags: html, css, forms, alignment

I'm trying to get a form horizontaly aligned, like it would be if I was using tables:

```
<form>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td style="width:30%"><label for="field1">Field1 Title:</label></td>
    <td><input type="text" id="field1" /></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Are you sure?</td>
    <td>
      <label for="sure_yes"> Yes </label><input type="radio" id="sure_yes" />&nbsp;
      <label for="sure_no"> No </label><input type="radio" id="sure_no" />
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td><input type="submit" value="Confirm" /></td>
  </tr>
</table>
</form>
```

I can define the generic css as block- displayed like this:

```
form label{
display:block;
float:left;
width:200px;
margin:5px 0;
clear:left;
}
form input, form textarea, form select{
display:block;
margin:5px 0;
clear:right;
float:left;
}
```

And in this case my HTML would look like this:

```
<form>
  <label for="field1">Field1 Title:</label>
  <input type="text" id="field1" />
  Are you sure?
  <label for="sure_yes"> Yes </label><input type="radio" id="sure_yes" />&nbsp;
  <label for="sure_no"> No </label><input type="radio" id="sure_no" />
  <input type="submit" value="Confirm" />
</form>
```

But of course this system won't work for my way of displaying radios and submit. I can fix this with a javascript function, but I wonder if there would be a pure css solution - and cross-browsers.

Comment: The above in http://jsfiddle.net/userdude/gdRC2/

Comment: When using css, you definitely want to stay away from class HTML elements in most cases (such as FORM, LABEL, TEXTAREA, etc...). Use CSS selectors to be more fine-grained, so you don't have unintended side effects on other elements you don't mean to style.

Comment: I don't agree with that. You can't simply through a statement like that around when each project is different. When coding forms, 99% of the time I stick to tag selectors rather than classes. It allows me to define a consistent feel of all elements throughout the site, which should follow consistent design. If, for whatever reason, there are 5 or 6 different form styles then add a class or id to the form element itself, thus allowing you to extend the base styles for that specific form.

Comment: @amustill - Let's agree to disagree. :)

Comment: Also, what you are suggesting is something closer to css normalization, which if you are using that kind of approach, you probably either know what you are doing, or don't know what you're in for. Either way, good luck.

Comment: I agree with Jared for most projects, but in this specific case I will stick with tag selectors as amustill recommends, as I know in advance for sure there won't be a surprise form that I might want to be displayed differently.

Comment: @Jared Farrish: Thanks for the fiddle! I never think of it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The solution is here: http://jsfiddle.net/gS86P/

The problem you had was you were trying to float the items. Instead I used inline-block and a row div to make them act similarly to a table, each row of the table in a separate row div.

Comment: Thanks! I don't like the fact each line is wrapped in a DIV, but the solution should involve setting a class for labels as you did. I'll see if I can get rid of the div.

Answer (score 0):

You can test this:

```
<form style="width:300px">
  <label for="field1" style="margin-right:20px;">Field1 Title:</label>
  <input type="text" id="field1" style="width:150px"/>
  <textarea style="border:none;background:none;color: #000000;font-size: 15px;resize: none;text-align: left;vertical-align: middle;font-family:'serif';max-width:60px; max-height:50px; overflow-y:hidden" disabled="disabled">Are you sure?</textarea>
  <label for="sure_yes" style="margin-top:12px;margin-left:35px" > Yes </label>
  <input type="radio" id="sure_yes" style="margin-top:17px" />
  <label for="sure_no" style="margin-top:12px" > No </label>
  <input type="radio" id="sure_no" style="margin-top:17px"  />
  <input type="submit" value="Confirm" style="margin-left:100px;"/>
</form>
```

Here I tried to do the job using only form element and css, though I am also novice to web programming.

Comment: Thanks but no, it's not what I want to achieve. My labels and fields shouldn't be styled individually.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution I used in the end:

CSS

```
.appui-form-label{
  display:block !important;
  margin:0.3em 2em 0.3em 0;
  padding-right: 60px;
  float:left !important;
  clear:left !important;
  vertical-align:top;
  position:relative;
  min-height:1.5em;
  white-space:nowrap;
  width: 200px;
}
.appui-form-field{
  display:block !important;
  margin:0.3em 0;
  float:left !important;
  clear:right !important;
  vertical-align:top;
  position:relative;
  width: 500px;
}
.appui-elem-hidden{
  display:none !important;
}
```

Javascript

```
(function($){
  $.fn.redraw = function(options){
    return this.each(function(){
      var ele = this,
        w = 0,
        center,
        total,
        cont,
        space,
        $lbl,
        $fld,
        $hiddenEle,
        $fieldsets = $("form", ele),
        $hiddenChildren = {};
      if ( $fieldsets.length > 0 ){
        $fieldsets.each(function(i){
          center = false, $hiddenEle = false, cont = this, $fieldset = $(this);
          $hiddenChildren = $hiddenChildren ?
            $fieldset.children(".appui-elem-hidden").removeClass("appui-elem-hidden") : 
            $hiddenChildren.add($fieldset.children(".appui-elem-hidden").removeClass("appui-elem-hidden"));

          $(".appui-form-label",cont).each(function(){
            $lbl = $(this);
            if ( $lbl.parents(":hidden").length > 0 ){
              $hiddenEle = $hiddenEle ? $hiddenEle.add($lbl.parents(":hidden").show()) : $lbl.parents(":hidden").show();
            }
            $lbl.css("width","auto");
            if ( $lbl.hasClass("appui-c") ){
              center = 1;
            }
            var w2 = $lbl.width();
            if ( w2 > w ){
              w = w2;
            }
            if ( !space ){
              $fld = $lbl.nextAll(".appui-form-field").first();
              space = ( $lbl.outerWidth(true) - $lbl.width() ) + ( $fld.outerWidth(true) - $fld.width() );
            }
          });
        });
        if ( w > 0 ){

          total = false;
          for ( var $par = $lbl.parent(); !total; $par = $par.parent() ){
            total = $par.width();
            if ( $par.width() < total ){
              total = $par.width();
            }
          }

          if ( total > 0 ){
            total -= ( 20 + space );
            if ( center ){
              var w1 = Math.round(total/2);
              w = w1;
            }
            else{
              var w1 = total - w;
            }
            $fieldsets.each(function(i){
              cont = this, $fieldset = $(this);
                $(".appui-form-label",cont).each(function(){
                  var $l = $(this);
                  $l.width(w);
                  if ( center ){
                    $l.css("text-align","right");
                  }
                  if ( $l.parent().prop("tagName").toLowerCase() === 'a' ){
                    $l = $l.parent();
                  }
                  var $f = $l.nextAll(".appui-form-field").first();
                  if ( $f.length === 0 ){
                    $f = $l.nextAll("a:first").find(".appui-form-field");
                  }
                  if ( $f.length === 0 ){
                    appui.f.log('Unable to find a corresponding field (' + $l.text() + ')');
                  }
                  else{
                    var t = $f.prop("tagName");
                    if ( t.toLowerCase() === 'div' || t.toLowerCase() === 'textarea' ){
                      $f.css("width",w1+"px");
                    }
                    else{
                      $f.css("max-width",w1+"px");
                    }
                  }
                });
            });
          }
          $hiddenChildren.addClass("appui-elem-hidden");
          if ( $hiddenEle ){
            $hiddenEle.hide();
          }
        }
      }
    });
  };
})(jQuery);
```